# kafka avro elasticsearch consumer allow unknown keys

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

Is there a way to allow Kafka-Avro to accept all keys from the producer, even when they aren't defined in the producers schema? Currently I'm running the producer with

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic elasticsearch-sink --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myRecord", "fields":[{"name":"esKey", type":"string"}]}'
```

And passing in
`{"esKey":"keyExample", "undefinedKey": "empty"}`

The Consumer will only show
`{"esKey":"keyExample"}`

And so the undefined key won't be sent to ElasticSearch either.
I'd rather not define the schema due to the input being very large and not predictable.

Edit: Working with Confluent 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema doesn't allow the other field

```
"fields":[{"name":"esKey", type":"string"}]
```

You need to add `undefinedKey` into this for that field to appear. Basically, the Avro deserializer doesn't have a reason to think that the other field should exist.

> I'd rather not define the schema due to the input being very large and not predictable.

Not clear what this means, but if you have unpredictable data, then perhaps Avro, or any strictly defined schema protocol, isn't the best choice?

Comment: Right, if I knew the what `undefinedKey` was when creating the schema, then I could include it. I was hoping there was a way to not include the complete schema (or any schema at all) when creating a producer, and allow all input to be sent to ElasticSearch.

Comment: Sure, you can use schemaless data (via normal producer} and send JSON directly. That's the only way you'll be able to get heterogeneous messages

Comment: Not at work atm so I can't reaffirm this, but when using the normal producer the data wasn't sent to ElasticSearch like it was with the avro producer. Is that normal or am I missing something?
Appreciate the help

Comment: If your record or schema is missing a field, then no consumer should be able to see those fields. I don't use Elastic sink regularly, so I don't know if I can help more than that